# Removing link from product thumbnail on cart page

Tags: php, templates, woocommerce, cart

How can I remove the link (but keep theproduct thumbnail image) fromthe following code

```
<?php
    $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

    if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
        echo $thumbnail; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
    } else {
        printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
    }
?>

It is part of the Woocommerce cart.php. I want to keep the link for the product name, but remove it from the thumbnail.
```

Comment: if the code goes to the `else` part, just change the printf call with this: `printf( '%s', $thumbnail );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To remove the product permalink from each cart item**, simply use the following into the functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', '__return_false' );
```

Tested and works.

---

**If you want to remove the product link only from the thumbnail in cart page use the following:**

First read [*"Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme"*](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) official documentation to understand how to Override WooCommerce templates via the active child theme (or active theme).

Once you have copied the template cart/cart.php into your theme as explained before, open edit it and replace the lines:

```
if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
    echo $thumbnail; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
} else {
    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
}
```

by:

```
echo $thumbnail;
```

You are done. The product link is now removed from the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks about how to remove the link from the product thumbnail on the cart page. The first solution from the LoicTheAztec [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493540/1354580) will remove the link both from the product thumbnail and product title, that is great, but even if it is necessary, it is too much.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', '__return_false' );
```

The second solution of the LoicTheAztec answer, implying a template override, is too complex for this. Less difficult is to add a second filter, in addition to the first solution, that will add back the link only to the product titles.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'add_back_product_link', 10, 2 );
function add_back_product_link( $cart_item_name,  $cart_item ) {
    $cart_item_name = '<a href="' . $cart_item['data']->get_permalink() . '">' . $cart_item_name . '</a>';
    return $cart_item_name;
}
```

Tested and works.