# Wrap product thumbnail on WooCommerce cart page in a span

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I'm using [Removing link from product thumbnail on cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493540/11987538) answer code to remove the permalink from the thumbnail image on the cart page.

Now I would like to wrap the thumbnail in a span or another element. I would like to leave the cart thumbnail intact. Is there a hook for this? I don't use a theme but a plugin.

Currently I am using the following code

```php
function custom_woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail($a) {

    $class = 'attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image'; // Default cart thumbnail class.
    $src = 'dummy';

    // Construct your img tag.
    $a = '<img';
    $a .= ' src="' . $src . '"';
    $a .= ' class="' . $class . '"';
    $a .= ' />';

    // Output.
    return $a;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'custom_woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 10, 3 );
```

---

Someone who can guide me on how to apply this?

Answer (score 1):

The [cart/cart.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/4.7/templates/cart/cart.php) template file contains (line 65-75)

```php
<td class="product-thumbnail">
<?php
$thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
    echo $thumbnail; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
} else {
    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
}
?>
</td>
```

This **ensures the output of the thumbnail with associated HTML** code

---

The `woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail` filter hook, first paramater contains `$_product->get_image()`

Which then leads us to the next code

```php
/**
 * Returns the main product image.
 *
 * @param  string $size (default: 'woocommerce_thumbnail').
 * @param  array  $attr Image attributes.
 * @param  bool   $placeholder True to return $placeholder if no image is found, or false to return an empty string.
 * @return string
 */
public function get_image( $size = 'woocommerce_thumbnail', $attr = array(), $placeholder = true ) {
    $image = '';
    if ( $this->get_image_id() ) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $this->get_image_id(), $size, false, $attr );
    } elseif ( $this->get_parent_id() ) {
        $parent_product = wc_get_product( $this->get_parent_id() );
        if ( $parent_product ) {
            $image = $parent_product->get_image( $size, $attr, $placeholder );
        }
    }

    if ( ! $image && $placeholder ) {
        $image = wc_placeholder_img( $size, $attr );
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_get_image', $image, $this, $size, $attr, $placeholder, $image );
}
```

which in turn invokes other functions.

---

---

However, because you want to keep the product thumbnail intact and wrap it in span tags, you can **just use**.

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail( $product_image, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Wrap the thumbnail in a span
    $product_image = '<span>' . $product_image . '</span>';
    
    return $product_image;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 10, 3 );
```

---

Note: if you want to change something in the  element you can use the [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) PHP function

Like:

```
$image = '<img src="myimage.jpg" width="500" height="600">';
```

Result before:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" width="500" height="600">
```

With [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
// Replace <img with <span><img
$image = str_replace( '<img', '<span><img', $image );
```

Result after:

```
<span><img src="myimage.jpg" width="500" height="600">
```

---

---

**Another option** is to overwrite the template file (see the answer you already referred to on how to apply), so in conjunction with that answer would

```php
if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
    echo $thumbnail; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
} else {
    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
}
```

Become

```
echo '<span>' . $thumbnail . '</span>';
```